# Calling minix _syscall() from within a function

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, minix

I have been running into a very strange problem in minix lately with regards to a system call I wrote.  Basically the code runs fine from within a main() function, and the call does what it should.  However, if I put the code in a function and call that function from within main(), it fails. Here is an example:

```
void do_foo()
{
    message m;
    _syscall(FS_PROC_NR, FOO, &m);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* works */
    message m;
    _syscall(FS_PROC_NR, FOO, &m);

    /* does not work */
    do_foo();
}
```

It seems that if you call a function from your code, it should do the same thing as if you just wrote the code in the main function.  What am I missing here??

Comment: Does that particular system call return before the operation is complete? If it does, then `m` is destroyed when `do_foo()` returns and the operation may either overwrite your stack, thinking `m` is still there, or get garbage from it, thinking the same. Or you may be feeding it wrongly sized `m`.

Comment: I thought it might be something like this, but in fact it had to do with my system call being in /usr/src/servers/vfs, and that I was not correctly loading a string pointer in the message with fetch_name, but instead was trying to directly pass the pointer to the string.  Still don't know why these two are different, but using fetch_name seems to fix it